# setting up boost libraries on mac El Capitan

Tags: c++, macos, boost

I have already spent hours on trying to set (link) boost libraries on my mac. First, I installed boost libraries using the homebrew package:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)";

$ brew update
$ brew install boost
```

it worked very nicely, but when I tried to install some custom package which makes use of boost, it got an error:

```
In file included from ToSig.cpp:7:
    ./libalgebra/libalgebra.h:33:10: fatal error: 'boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp' file not found
    #include <boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp>
             ^
    1 warning and 1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

which simply means, that the path is not set correctly.

After googling a lot, I was advised to use the macports installer, to install boost, which sets the path, but it didn't help either.

When I tried to run a simple code using Xcode:

```
include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
                  in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

, I got the same error ("boost/lambda/lambda.hpp" is not found)

Is there a simple, yet effective way to install boost libraries and link them properly?

Comment: I suppose you were installing [CoRoPa](https://coropa.sourceforge.io)..did you manage to get this working?

Comment: @IvanAbraham, right. Are you interested in ESig package?

Comment: Yes. I was trying to do the `pip install` command and got the same error.

Comment: try this one: https://sourceforge.net/projects/coropa/files/ESig-2017-06-07/

Comment: this is the latest release and should work on macOS. Next month (or so), they should release an online version, so you'' be able to do direct `pip install esig` from the online repo.

Comment: Thank you very much! Il try it out.

Comment: If you are interested in further applications of the signature method, stay in touch.